# Disable step in Visual Studio Extension build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions

While I am building own Visual Studio Extension in TeamCity (same applies to any CI server build that supports building VS solutions), my build stucks on the step `DeployVsixExtensionFiles`. As far as I understand, the target is defined in VS Extensibility files and is being imported into any .csproj by default. I also realize that this is an "aka test" step that tries to embed an extension into a virtual copy of VS via running a command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /RootSuffix Exp /ResetSettings General.vssettings /Embedding /Command File.Exit
```

I have two questions:
1. Should I disable this step for Release build of Extension?
2. If yes, how can this be done.

Comment: Not so clear about your issue. Do you mean deploy VSIX project?
>> Should I disable this step for Release build of Extension
In my opinion, it is based on requirement. 
>> how can this be done.
In project file (.csproj), set deploy extension to false in the PropertyGroup section ( <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">). <DeployExtension>False</DeployExtension>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VS SDK installs the extension as a part of a build so you can F5 and run it. If you're CI system doesn't care about that, update your CI configuration to pass `/p:DeployExtension=false` to MSBuild.